# How to use map to pad characters "_" to strings whose length is less?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to use map to pad characters "_" to strings whose length is less?

My code:

```
    lst = ['photo', 'music', 'magazine']
def all_eq(lst):
    max_item = max(lst, key = lambda x: len(x))
    max_len = len(max_item)
    for i in lst:
        if len(i) < max_len:
            b = list(map(lambda x: x + "_", lst))
    return b

print(all_eq(['photo', 'music', 'magazine']))
```

Comment: You're not adding the "right" number of `"_"`. You need `max_len - len(x)` many.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `str.rjust` (or `str.ljust`, depending on the desired padding direction).

> rjust(self, width, fillchar=' ', /)
> Return a right-justified string of length width.
>
> ```
> Padding is done using the specified fill character (default is a space).
> ```

Example:

```
>>> lst = ['photo', 'music', 'magazine']
>>> max_len = max(map(len, lst))
>>> padded = [e.rjust(max_len, "_") for e in lst]
>>> padded
['___photo', '___music', 'magazine']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use f-string padding in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = ['photo', 'music', 'magazine']
>>> max_len = max(map(len, lst))
>>> [f'{s:_>{max_len}}' for s in lst]
['___photo', '___music', 'magazine']
>>> [f'{s:_<{max_len}}' for s in lst]
['photo___', 'music___', 'magazine']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string formatting, see [link](https://pyformat.info/).

```
def all_eq(lst):
    max_item = len(max(lst, key=len))
    return list(map(f'{{:_<{max_item}}}'.format, lst))
```

In this case the padding character take place to the end of the string. Change with `>` for the opposite behavior.

---

A more flexible way. Supported paddings: `<`, '>', '^' (centered)

```
def all_eq(lst, padding='<', sep='_'):
    max_item = len(max(lst, key=len))
    return list(map(f'{{:{sep}{padding}{max_item}}}'.format, lst))

lst = ['photo', 'music', 'magazine']

print(all_eq(lst, padding='^', sep='@'))
#['@photo@@', '@music@@', 'magazine']
```